# Help with a summary report and formula

Tags: formula, reporting

I have a summary report with 3 groupings- Opp Owner, Their Sales Consultants, and then a row level formula to group opportunities by stage into won or lost.  I have 2 summary row formulas using parentgroupval to get sales consultants % of record count and sales amount.
How can I get the  total of” % of Quotes Flipped” and “% of Sales Amount on Quotes” for each Owner? Is this possible.  I’d like it on the opportunity owner for both total won and total lost.
I have created a separate report excluding the second group of sales consultant and can do it that way, but I’d like to have it in one report to bring onto a dashboard in one component.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using a row level to group Lost/Win? can't you just group by stage and if you don't want the other stages filter them out. why does it matter if you get the totals for "% of Quotes Flipped” and “% of Sales Amount on Quotes” it looks like they be 100% regaurdless

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).